# Can I use google service accounts to authenticate INCOMING requests?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

We currently have an App Engine application plus some Google Compute Engine backends.  Unfortunately App Engine is not considered "in-network" so in order for App Engine to make requests to backend servers, the relevant ports must be made publicly available in the firewall which is obviously a security risk.  It would be very convenient if our App Engine app could automatically "sign" all request to our backends by using a service account client to issue the requests.  Is this possible?

And likewise, I'd love to also do this in the other direction, where requests *from* our GCE servers could be authenticated by App Engine as long as the requests are issued from a GCE service account.  I naively tried the latter by issuing a request from GCE to a test handler on app engine that checks the current user (via the Users service) but unsurprisingly the user was null (since "users" and "service accounts" aren't exactly the same I didn't expect this to work - but hey worth a shot).

There's a fair amount of info on the web for *issuing* service-account-authenticated requests (e.g. to google APIs) but I can't find anything on *authenticating* incoming requests.  Does such a thing exist?  (ideally in Go)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature coming out soon called Managed VMs. You can click on the following link for more details and signup for updates https://developers.google.com/cloud/managed-vms.

Comment: Oh I've been following managed VMs closely (and have requested access), I'd just rather not rely on them 100% (in part since they aren't here yet) - hence exploring the approach above.

Comment: Ian, this is great feedback. I'm not currently aware of a method for doing this, but I'll make sure that folks know there's demand for it.